# Post async method invalidate session using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to execute a @async method in a Spring Aplication. The controller even doesn't reach to execute and session is invalidated (I supuse the problem is in chain filtering) and the application is redirected to de login page (result URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/login?logout=true).

There isn't errors on the standar output.

I've intented many options but I haven't found someone that works.

Thanks.

CODE: The following code works when the login do de post on my custom Authentication Provider (/auth/dopost) but not /visor/publishenv who executes a async method.

Spring version: 5.4.2
JDK: OpenJdk 16

Controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/visor")
public class PublishController
{

    @Autowired
    private AmbienteClient ambienteClient;

    @Autowired
    private PublishAsyncService publishService;

    @PostMapping("/publishenv")
    public String publish(PublishData sala, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
    {
        Ambiente ambiente = ambienteClient.getAmbbienteById(sala.getAmbienteid()).getBody();
        if (ambiente != null)
        {
            try
            {
                publishService.runTransmitStream(ambiente, sala.getPin());
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("test2", "Publicando " + ambiente.getNombre());
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("test2", "Ha ocurrido un error interno.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("test2", "Error al recuperar el ambiente.");
        }
        return "redirect:/visor/publicar";
    }
}
```

Service

```java
@Service
public class PublishAsyncService
{

    @Autowired
    private SalasRepository salasRepo;

    @Autowired
    private VisorParams vParams;

    @Async
    public void runTransmitStream(Ambiente ambiente, int pin) throws InterruptedException
    {
        try
        {
            DBSalas dbsala = null;
            Set<Integer> inUsePorts = new TreeSet<>();
            List<DBSalas> salasActivas = salasRepo.findByEstado(1);
            for (DBSalas dbs : salasActivas)
            {
                if (Objects.equals(dbs.getAmbienteid(), ambiente.getId()))
                {
                    dbsala = dbs;
                }
                inUsePorts.add(dbs.getPuerto());
            }

            if (dbsala == null)
            {
                dbsala = DBSalas.builder()
                        .ambienteid(ambiente.getId())
                        .ambiente(ambiente)
                        .usuarioid("test")
                        .fec_hora_inicio(new Date())
                        .estado(1)
                        .pin(pin)
                        .puerto(Ports.getAvailablePort(inUsePorts))
                        .build();
                dbsala = salasRepo.save(dbsala);
                List<String> lst = new LinkedList<>();
                lst.add(vParams.getCommand());
                lst.add(ambiente.getCamara().getStreamUri(vParams.getInputprotocol()));
                lst.add(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:" + dbsala.getPuerto() + "/" + dbsala.getPin() + "}");
                lst.add(":sout-all");
                lst.add(":sout-keep");
   
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
                pb.command(lst);
                Process p = pb.start();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                long pid = p.pid();
                dbsala.setPid(pid);
                dbsala = salasRepo.save(dbsala);
                salasRepo.flush();
                p.waitFor();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Async config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class PublishAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer
{

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("visor-");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        return new AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {

            @Override
            public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex,
                    Method method, Object... params)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Method Name: " + method.getName());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Auth config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthenticateConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private PortalAuthProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        String[] publicUriAcces =
        {
            "/", "/auth/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**"
        };

        String[] postAcces =
        {
            "/visor/publishenv", "/auth/dologin"
        };

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicUriAcces).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/visor/publishenv").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/visor/index", true)
                .failureUrl("/auth/login?error=true")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/dologin")
                .permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("Usuario")
                .passwordParameter("SessionId")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login?logout=true")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                ;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what did your debug logs tell you after you enabled them? because surely you must have read the debug logs before posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that for antmatchers "/visor/publishenv" has permitted to only **admin and user** make sure you have given correct access.

Comment: Hi Narasimha, thanks for replying. Yes, I've checked  the antmatchers and the user logged have the corrects roles and I've even tried set .permitAll() instead .hasAnyRole() without success

Comment: can you check the redirect url of  **/visor/publicar** in **/publishenv**. you have to give access to that end point also. @NicolásNavarro.